# launch4j generated exe error - invalid or a corrupt jar file

Tags: java, windows, launch4j

I used launch4j utility to generate an exe from a jar file. Exe is generated just fine but when I try to run it, I see an error
"Error: invalid or a corrupt jar file"

Can someone please explain what's going on here? I have validated the jar file and also can run it independently, just fine.
Also I don't think this is about signing the exe as I am able to generate unsigned exe from other jar files and run it fine.

Thanks.

Comment: [jar2exe](http://www.jar2exe.com) is a far better alternative